# C++: returning shared pointer destroys the object

Tags: c++, memory

I'm trying to return a new `shared_ptr` from a method:

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<VertexBuffer> VertexBuffer::Create(float* vertices, uint32_t size)
{
    return std::make_shared<OpenGLVertexBuffer>(std::move(OpenGLVertexBuffer(vertices, size)));
}
```

I have a destructor and `VertexBuffer` gets destroyed after exiting this method. Why is that?

Comment: Are the types `OpenGLVertexBuffer` and `VertexBuffer` related? Because you promised to return one and you actually returned the other

Comment: OpenGLVertexBuffer extends VertexBuffer

Comment: Which `VertexBuffer` gets destroyed? The one owned by the shared pointer, or the one you called the method on? Or the temporary one you explicitly moved from?

Comment: In the code you construct a the stack `OpenGLVertexBuffer` then move-construct a `OpenGLVertexBuffer` from it on a newly allocated memory on the heap. On exit the stack constructed `OpenGLVertexBuffer` will be destroyed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The destructor is being called on this temporary object:

```
return std::make_shared<OpenGLVertexBuffer>(std::move(OpenGLVertexBuffer(vertices, size)));
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You're slightly misusing `std::make_shared` and invoking the move/copy constructor instead. This shouldn't be a correctness issue if your class follows the [Rule of Three/Five/Zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)), but it is inefficient.

You should instead directly construct the object using `std::make_shared` as intended, which is to *forward* constructor arguments rather than constructing an object explicitly.

```
return std::make_shared<OpenGLVertexBuffer>(vertices, size);
```

Also note that calling `std::move(x)` where `x` already is a temporary achieves nothing.

Comment: _"Also note that calling `std::move(x)` where `x` already is a temporary achieves nothing."_ -- actually this practice can be worse than nothing. In C++17 such a practice can prevent copy-elision since it converts the PRValue into an XValue. This doesn't apply to this exact circumstance since `std::make_shared` will forward the reference anyway, but if it's being done here, it's likely being done elsewhere.

Comment: In addition, the energy used with the extra typing hastens the heat-death of the universe.

Comment: @user4581301 • All part of Project Boil The Oceans.  **Superfluous std::move** the new anti-pattern.

Comment: The Superfluous std::move... Sounds like  Lee/Ditko comic from the 60s.